# Maven depedencies for wildfly 10 server to support ejb,jms

Tags: maven, wildfly-10

i am new to wildfly 10 server. I am going to develop one application using ejb, jms, MQ, maven technologies. Which wildfly 10 jars I have to use in my maven POM file to support ejb, jms?

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly 10 already provides all jars you need.
In your case it should be enough to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now you implement against the api and have the dependencies for compilation. At deployment and runtime wildfly will provide the implementation.